# Return specific data at specific iteration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I Have a container that holds a bunch of cards that hold data (the card is `property-card` and the data its holding is the `html` tag). I want `modalContent` to hold the data of the specific `property-card` that I'm clicking on. The problem is that `modelContent` is holding the data of the `property-card` at the last iteration of the loop, not the one I'm clicking on.

```
 fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/properties?BuildingUse=${BuildingUse}&MinUnits=${MinUnits}&MaxUnits=${MaxUnits}&CommunitySearch=${CommunitySearch}`)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      
   
      
      let resultsContainer = document.getElementById('resultsContainer');
      let modalContent = document.getElementById('modal-card'); 
      
      if (data.length === 0) {
        resultsContainer.innerText = 'No results';
      } else {
        let html = '';
        let streetViewUrl;
        let modalHtml = '';
        let modalHtmls = [];

        const ownerMapping = {
        'PRIV': 'Private',
        'UN': 'Unknown'
      };
        

        data.forEach(function(property, index) {
        
      streetViewUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=${encodeURIComponent(property.CIVIC_ADDRESS) + "," + property.COMMUNITY_NAME + " NS"}&key=AIzaSyCydOglnt_lzCLRIVGpR4U4vl6TmK1rXWE`;
      const ownerDescription = ownerMapping[property.BUILDING_OWNER] || property.BUILDING_OWNER;
        

        html += `
            <div class="property-card">
              <img class="property-img" src="${streetViewUrl}" alt="Street view of ${property.CIVIC_ADDRESS}">
              <h2 class="property-address">${property.CIVIC_ADDRESS}, ${property.COMMUNITY_NAME}, NS</h2>
              <p class="property-units">Dwelling Units: ${property.DWELLING_UNITS}</p>
              <p class="property-owner">Building Owner: ${ownerDescription}</p>
              <p class="property-owner">Property ID: ${property.PID}</p>
              <p class="property-use">Building Use: ${property.BUILDING_USE}</p>
              <a class="property-info" href="https://linns.novascotia.ca/property-online/secure/property/land-title/view.do?pid=${property.PID}">View Property Online Info</a>
              
            </div>`;

        let currentModalHtml = `
        <div class="property-card">
          <div class="left-grid">
              <h2 class="property-address">${property.CIVIC_ADDRESS}, ${property.COMMUNITY_NAME}, NS</h2>
              <p class="property-units">Dwelling Units: ${property.DWELLING_UNITS}</p>
              <p class="property-owner">Building Owner: ${ownerDescription}</p>
              <p class="property-owner">Property ID: ${property.PID}</p>
              <p class="property-use">Building Use: ${property.BUILDING_USE}</p>
              <a class="property-info" href="https://linns.novascotia.ca/property-online/secure/property/land-title/view.do?pid=${property.PID}">View Property Online Info</a>
          </div>
          <div class="right-grid">
              <img class="modal-property-img" src="${streetViewUrl}" alt="Street view of ${property.CIVIC_ADDRESS}">
              <div class=Calc>
              <h3 class=CalcTitle></h3>
              <select id="Calculator" name="Calculator">
              <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose a Calculator</option>
              <option value=""></option>
              <option class = "GPI" value="GPI">Gross Potential Income (GPI)</option>
              <option value="GOI">Gross Operation Income (GOI)</option>
              <option value="NOI">Net Operating Income (NOI)</option>
              <option value="CapRate">Capitalization Rate (Cap Rate)</option>
              <option value="PricePerUnit">Price Per Unit</option>
            </select>
            <div class="gpiBox"> hi</div>
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>`;

            modalHtmls.push(currentModalHtml);

        
      

        resultsContainer.innerHTML = html;
        modalContent.innerHTML = modalHtmls[index];
        

       


      });
    }
    })
```

```
  document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const modal = document.querySelector(".modal-card");
    
    
    if (modal.style.display === "block") {
       
        if (!modal.contains(event.target) && event.target !== modal) {
            
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    } else {
      
        if (event.target.closest('.property-card')) {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
});
```

I tried holding the data in an array and use an `index` counter to match the  iterations data but it didn't work...

Comment: by using event delegation u can achieve this you can attach event listener to container that holds property cards and then determine which card was clicked. Based on this clicked card you can show corresponding modal content.